# Maven exception while running the TestNG testsuite from command prompt or jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, log4j

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Here is my updated pom.xml

Now I am running following command
**mvn install -Pbizom -                 DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/java/suite/testng_OrderSanity.xml**

I have tried with different log4j version but not working.

This is my updated pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mobisy.bizom</groupId>
    <artifactId>bizom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>          
         <extentreports.version>2.40.2</extentreports.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>
              UTF-8 
    </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            UTF-8 
    </project.reporting.outputEncoding>

</properties>
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>bizom</id>             
 <properties>

       <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/suite/testng_OrderSanity.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </properties>
            <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>

                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.19.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <properties>
                                    <property>
                                        <name>listener</name>            
                          <value>bizom.listener.CustomListener</value>
                                    </property>
                                </properties>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}
                 </suiteXmlFile>
                                </suiteXmlFiles>
                   <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                                <classpathDependencyScopeExclude>runtime</classpathDependencyScopeExclude>
                                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                                <printSummary>true</printSummary>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.0</version>
                        </plugin>
                         <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                             <version>2.19.1</version>
                             <executions>
                                 <execution>
                                     <goals>
                                         <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                         <goal>verify</goal>
                                     </goals>
                                 </execution>
                             </executions>
                         </plugin>
                    </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8-beta4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <type>jar</type>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>${extentreports.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>      
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

But when I am running it through command prompt by below command:

```
**mvn install -Pbizom -DsuiteXmlFile=src/test/java/suite/testng_OrderSanity.xml**
```

**Now facing new error:**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project bizom: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
    [ERROR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Priority
    [ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    [ERROR] atorg.testng.internal.ClassHelper.newInstance(ClassHelper.java:65)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.setListenerClasses(TestNG.java:695)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.configure(TestNG.java:1534)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.configure(TestNG.java:1707)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNGMapConfigurator.configure(TestNGMapConfigurator.java:52)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:277)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
    [ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Priority
    [ERROR] at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    [ERROR] asun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    [ERROR] at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)


Now its taking 2.19.1 but still error is coming. I have tried with different log4j version but not working.
```

Comment: First having a maven plugin as dependency is simply wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise Please tell me where do i have to change and what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build is effectively using Surefire `2.17`:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:**2.17**:test

But you defined `2.19.1` as dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
```

Thus version `2.17` is actually running but `2.19.1` classes are on your classpath and used at runtime, obviously that is not compatible. New methods were added betwween `2.19` that were not present in `2.17`.

You defined version `2.19.1` as plugins under `pluginManagement`, but it is not currently used in your build. If you want to use `2.19.1` in your current build your should use `plugins` and not `pluginManagement`. If you are not sure about the difference between `pluginManagement` and `plugins`, I strongly recommend you see the [Maven doc](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Putting `maven-surefire-plugin` config outside of `pluginManagement` and removing the `dependency` of type `<type>maven-plugin</type>` should to the trick.

Comment: I have removed "pluginManagement" and now using plugins only and also removed <type>maven-plugin</type> but still on same page.It's not working, still it's taking 2.17 instead of 2.19.1. Please Help!

Comment: You need to remove the dependency completely, not just the type. Remove the `maven-compiler-plugin` from your `dependencies`. The only reference to this should be under your `plugins` ;)

Comment: I have removed it from dependencies now maven-compiler-plugin only in plugins but still not working

Comment: Is it the same error? Can you edit your answer and provide the updated pom?

Comment: Have uploaded the updated pom.xml file, please look into it.

Comment: You are still running the `2.17` version. You configured the 2.19.1 in the `bizom` profile but it seems you don't use it... Try to run `mvn -Pbizom clean install` or define your plugin configuration outside of any profile.

Comment: Have uploaded the updated pom.xml file and now new error is coming . Please have a look.

Comment: Great! I believe your original issue has been solved: Surefire 2.19 is now running fine but your new issue is with one of your TestNG listener. From what you show, it's probably with your configured Listener and the plugin class loader. I'd recommand you keep your original question/issue and post a new question with this issue, otherwise people might get confused, your current question is quite different than the original one.